# Picture cannot display Django

Tags: python, django

I've issue  related with displaying image from Model.I have caption instead of picture. I don't know what is the cause of that .

```
 from django.db import models

class Games(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images_game',default='' )
  # def __str__ (self):
   # return self.Name

class Game_detail(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Games,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcryption = models.TextField()
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date_of_publish = models.DateField()

class Order(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    person_surname = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    city= models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    from .models import Games,Game_detail,Order
    from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
    from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView,CreateView

        class IndexView(ListView):
            template_name ='games/list.html'
            context_object_name = 'all_games'
            model = Games
            def get_queryset(self):
                return Games.objects.all()


        class Item_Detail (DetailView):

            context_object_name = 'object'
            template_name ='games/detail.html'
            model = Games # tu jest wazna zmiana

            def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
                context = super(DetailView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
                context['Game_detail']=Game_detail.objects.all()
                return context



        class Create_order (CreateView):
            template_name ='games/create.html'
            model= Order
            fields = ['person_name','person_surname','street','city']
```

settings.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^games/',include("games.urls")),
   ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

list.html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
{% for obj in all_games%}
<a href ='{%url "detail" pk=obj.pk%}'>{{obj.name}}</a>
{{obj.image}}
{{obj.platform}}
{{obj.genre}}
{{obj.language}}
{% endfor %}


</body>
</html>
```

I think it would be problem with right track to the picture . I added the picture in database and image upload to folder

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify in your template

```
<img src="{{obj.image.url}}" />.
```

You are storing the upload path in the database, so in the src you can have the obj.image entered and should be able to see the image just fine.

Comment: <img src="{{obj.image.url}}" />. That works but I not could  set the width and heigh  <img src="{{obj.image.url}}" style="width:100px;height:50px;"> Image didn't display